# How can I get the "row" from indexPathsForSelectedRows?

Tags: ios, nsindexpath

I am trying to get the "row" value from indexPathsForSelectedRows.

```
NSArray *selectedCells = [self.storeTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSLog(@"%@",[selectedCells objectAtIndex:0]);
```

This NSLog prints out

```
<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000008016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}
```

How can I just get the number '4' as an integer in this example?

I've tried objectForKey@"path". but it did not work.

Comment: You should consult the [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007175) reference.

Comment: Use this  NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; and get this as selectedIndexPath.row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
NSArray *selectedCells = [self.storeTableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
NSIndexPath *firstIndexPath = [selectedCells objectAtIndex:0];
NSUInteger row = firstIndexPath.row
```

and `row` will be `4` in your case.